# Tag rename request: balay-stance -> belay-stance

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's a typo in the tag name [balay-stance](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balay-stance). Could a mod rename it to "belay-stance" please?

Comment: Just remove the tag and add a new one with the correct spelling, no need for a mod to do it

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Done! I didn't realize that the old tag would automagically disappear when it was removed from its only question.